Which parts of an F1 engine are most prone to wear and tear over time?
Which parts of an F1 engine are most prone to wear and tear over time and why if metal is not in contact with metal, always is oil film between, so how wear become?
If wear hapend(what is true) that mean metal must somehow comes in contact  with metal..
same question apply to car engines.

There are several things which could cause wear in an engine, even with oil providing between metal parts to prevent wear. Two things to remember:

Oil breaks down over time. Brand new oil provides much better wear protection than does old oil.
Also as oil gets older, more impurities become present. These impurities can cause wear whether or not the oil itself is providing space between the metal pieces.

Primarily with my second bullet, impurities can be anything from dirt grit to loose floating carbon. With enough of it in the oil, it can cause the wear you're talking about. Even if only a small bit of wear, throw in a few hundred thousand revolutions of the crankshaft and you'll see wear. Oil filters can do only so much. If they get "full" where there is too much back pressure, the filter itself can start letting unfiltered oil through, because dirty oil lubrication is better on an engine than no oil at all.
There's basically no difference from an F1 engine to a regular engine as far as what parts are more prone to wear. The main parts which will wear first/most are the rings, bearings, and seals. The huge difference is, an F1 engine is built to last a few hundred miles to cover the length of the race. It will then get rebuilt, or at a minimum torn down and inspected. A regular engine is built to last for a few hundred thousand miles (at least by today's standards). While the wear parts are the same, the amount of wear they'll see is far different.

@Paulster2 but what wear rings in hunders km so much if ring dont touch wall? that part I dont understand

At high pressures fluids can wear out things. Oil reduces friction, it doesn't remove it.

@22flower - I'm not sure you read what I wrote? I explained at least two things which can cause the wear to happen. And wear happens so much faster in F1 engines than it does in regular engines since F1 engines only have to last a few hundred miles.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes I read. F1 use new oil every race so oil cant be problem

@22flower - Why do you think there's a problem? You asked where the wear occurs, but that's not the same as how much wear occurs. I don't think F1 engines run the several hundred miles and die ... it'd still run just fine. Doesn't mean they don't strip it all the way down and rebuild it ready for the next race.
